# Javascript function not executing and not returning an array

Tags: javascript, express

Cart.js

```
var Cart = function Cart(oldCart) {
this.items =  oldCart.items || [];


this.add = function (item) {
    this.items.push(item);
    }
}
```

My index.js route

```
 router.post('/cart', (function (req, res) {
    var productid = req.body.id
    var myCart = new Cart(req.session.cart ? req.session.cart :{})

    //query the db and return the correct object
    Products.findById({ _id: productid }, function (err, product) {
        //if there is an error...
        if (err) {
            return res.redirect('/');
        }

        myCart.add(product);
        req.session.cart = myCart;
        console.log(req.session.cart);
        res.redirect('/');

    });
```

}));

At the end of your code example, you included this code that I assume it is the code for cart.js

```
 function Cart(oldCart = {}) {
  this.items = oldCart.items || [];
  this.add = function (item) {
    this.items.push(item)
  }
}
```

but it gives me error with (oldCart= {}) as parameter. so I removed that.
Now, I get one item added to the shopping cart everytime I press on an item. It doesn't include items that clicked on previously.

Here is the console.log, notice 'Strawberry' is in my first request, and then I was redirected to the index page and clicked on 'Apple', it is suppose to accumulate the product in the second request to show Cart:['Strawberry', 'Apple']

[image]

When I run your code where I add product2 and product2 to the shopping cart, this is how it display the shopping cart which is correct because it is showing two items in the shopping cart which is the normal behavior.

[image]

I thank you so much for your time and apologize for taking time away from you

Do I need to use for loop to go over the myCart object to display all items in there instead of what I added last?

Comment: because in your `cart.js` file, `cart.add` is a `function`

Comment: I passed the product and product.name to the function in the index.js. Is not it suppose to add that this.items and generateArray to push that to the array?

Comment: You're not calling the functions. You are only printing to the console what the `cart` object looks like

Comment: When I call the Cart function like this : cart(product, productid) and it gives me an error that cart is not a function? Is not calling a function is passing the parameters to the function like : cart.add(argument1, argument2)?

Comment: the only time you can pass an argument to `Cart()` is when you instantiate it like this: `new Cart(argument)`. To use `cart.add`, call it like a function: `cart.add(arg, arg2)`

Comment: I see. So If I instantiate it like this var cart = new Cart (product.name, product.price) that is all I need and then req.session.cart will print the cart correctly with name and price of the product? Right?

Comment: Thank you Jason. I understand the concept now. However, when I removed the cart.add() and cart.generateArray. The console.log is just showing the cart with the function like this: Cart{items:{}, add:[function], generateArray:[function]} ....So now I'm lost, why the code is not taking me argument of product.name and add it to the array?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160234/discussion-between-josan-iracheta-and-marco).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you explained to me what it is you are trying to accomplish, I will help you do it in the easiest way possible.

We will start by re-formatting your code. Your `items` property is currently an object `{}` but we are going to use an array `[]` instead.

```
`this.items = oldCart.items || []`
```

Since `items` is now an array, we will `push` new items into it using the `add` method that you created. I modified it to this:

```
this.add = function(item){
   this.items.push(item);
  }
```

And that's all you need. Now in your code, after you fetch a product for the database, add it to `cart.items` and then pass that to your session:

```
Products.findById({ _id: productid }, function (err, product) {
  if (err) {
    return res.redirect('/');
  }
  //add the product to cart.items
  cart.add(product)
  //pass cart.items to the session
  req.session.cart = cart.items;
  req.session.save(function (err) {
    return
  });
```

```js
//instantiate new cart object
const myCart = new Cart;
const product1 = {id:1, name:'orange', price:1};
const product2 = {id:2, name:'apple', price:2};
//add products
myCart.add(product1);
myCart.add(product2);
//you can see the added products
console.log(myCart.items)

function Cart(oldCart = {}) {
  this.items = oldCart.items || [];
  this.add = function (item) {
 this.items.push(item)
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated my code and question above. Please read. Thank you so much for taking the time to help. That was extremely helpful. I think I need to use for loop to get all items added to ITEMS in the cart to fix the issue displaying one item in cart session? Right?

Comment: @marco you have to instantiate the class only once. Try instantiating it outside of `Products.findBy...`

Comment: Hi Jason, If instantiate the const myCart = new Cart; outside the products.findById, then I don't have access to the "product" object that returned.  If I moved it out of that function, then it gives me error "can't read property "items" of undefined.

Comment: @marco I'm glad you were able to figure it out :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'll reach out in the future for more help lol